# How to UNION ALL specific tables based on a Parameter condition

Tags: mysql, sql, parameters, case, union

Say I have a global parameter `param_filtered` where the value can be 0 or 1, and i have already created tables `main`, `transactions` and `transactions_filtered`, all three tables return the same number of fields

Now i am trying to do a **UNION ALL** query on the tables, but i will need UNION ALL the `transactions` or `transactions_filtered` based on the parameter condition

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM main
UNION ALL
CASE WHEN param_filtered > 0
THEN 
SELECT * FROM transactions_filtered
ELSE
SELECT * FROM transactions
```

but it did not work. Is there a way to do UNION specific tables only based on a parameter condition?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you do this in a stored procedure with an input of param filtered and IF..Else..end if; construct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the condition in the `WHERE` clause of the union'd queries.

Its a variable equivalent to `where 1=1` which always evaluates `true` to select all rows and `where 1=2` which always evaluates `false` to prevent any rows from being selected

```
set @paramfiltered := 1

SELECT * FROM main
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM transactions_filtered WHERE @paramfiltered > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE @paramfiltered <= 0
```

Here is a sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6bba3/1

Comment: Seriously? the code will expect param_filtered to be a column in the table whereas OP wants a global parameter to elect which table to read from

Comment: I've set the parameter and added a sqlfiddle to demonstrate

Comment: Yes I should have added that I am doing a Stored Procedure too. I tested out the solution and it works! Thanks @Simeon !